# Vue.js - Typeahead Directive

Tags: vue.js, typeahead.js, vuejs2

### Vue.js Directive for Typeahead

I am trying to write a `Vue Directive` for `typeahead.js` functionality.  I was able to instantiate `typeahead` on the `input form control` and also assign it `options` and `dataset`.  `Event handling` too was not a problem.

### The Issue :

Now, I also want to control the `typeahead input element` from the `component`.  For example, I would like to control these methods `$(el).typeahead('destroy')` or `$(el).typeahead('open')`, etc. from the component.

How can i call these methods from the Component? Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I just figured it out 2 minutes after typing the question.

I add a `ref` to the `input tag`.

```
<!-- bindings is an object which has the "options" and "dataset" -->
<input ref="ttInput" v-typeahead="bindings" />
```

Then, I have added a method in the `component` which executes `typeahead` methods from the `component`:

```
...
methods: {
  methodHook (action) {
    const el = this.$refs.ttInput
    $(el).typeahead(action)
  }
}
...
```

So, now, in the `html template`, i can have a `button/buttons`:

```
<button type="button" @click="methodHook('open')" >Open</button>
<button type="button" @click="methodHook('close')">Close</button>
```

Works like a charm.

Thanks